# Next 13 without src folder middleware problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Im using next 13 without the src folder. Im applying the middleware in the root of my application and the middleware is being runned in my models folder how do i prevent this

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { options } from "./app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/options";
import upload from "@utils/multer";

export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export async function middleware(req) {
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  const session = await getSession(options);
  console.log(path);

  // Check if the route is protected (e.g., not a public route) and the user is not logged in
  const isProtectedRoute = path !== "/"; // Add other protected routes as needed
  if (isProtectedRoute && !session) {
    return NextResponse.redirect("/");
  }

  // Apply file upload logic only for the specific route
  if (path === "/home") {
    upload.single("image")(req, null, err => {
      if (err) {
        if (err.code === "LIMIT_FILE_SIZE") {
          return NextResponse.next({
            status: 413,
            body: "File is too large",
          });
        }
        return NextResponse.next({
          status: 400,
          body: err.message,
        });
      }
    });
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  // Add other protected routes to the matcher as needed
  matcher: ["/"],
};
```

[image]

I am trying to protect my routes if the user has not logged in but my code is not working

Comment: Do you know, as of know, your middleware will only run when someone visits your root project, aka `/`, because of your `config`.